# What is the most effective way to style a Flex application?

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex, flash-cs3

This may be more of an opinion poll than a question, but here goes.  I have a fairly complex Flex application that uses many different components.  I want the application to be able to custom styling and/or skinning.  I also want to be sure that the styling approach makes the most efficient use of system resources (memory, CPU, network), and that it does not adversely impact performance.

We currently are using a hybrid approach to styling the application that uses both CSS and a Flash skin created in CS3.  It seems odd to me to have a two-pronged approach to styling an application and ideally would like to settle on one approach or the other.  Can someone outline the advantages and disadvantages of using either exclusively CSS or a Flash skin?  Is there a justification for using both within the same app?

Using CSS exclusively seems advantageous because it is approachable by anyone with a basic understanding of other uses of CSS, especially when using the Flex 2 Style Explorer.  On the other hand, I know that the CS3 skin we use declares up/over/down/disabled/pressed skins for each component where these states are needed and Flex manages the transitions to the appropriate skins as each state is (de)activated.   However, my impression is that creation of a Flex skin in CS3 requires somewhat specialized skills and tools.

So what would you recommend for styling a Flex application if performance, customization, and efficient resource utilization are priorities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would suggest using Flex 4 if you haven't started already.  [Flex 4 is just about to be released](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4).

With Flex 4, they have a whole new [skinning architecture](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Gumbo+Skinning).  This means you'll never use Programmatic Skins again.  Plus they have [Advanced CSS Selectors](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors), so you can do way more with CSS in Flex 4.  Programmatic Skins are very hard to make dynamic anyways.  In the end, you'll end up creating an architecture like Flex 4 Spark Skins if you try to abstract out the logic for Programmatic Skins.

### Customization

What we're doing to make Flex 4 Skins and Styling as dynamic as possible is the following:

- Style Palletes: Either static classes, or XML files
- Custom Skins
- CSS

**Style Palletes**: These are static classes that hold all of the variables you use in either CSS or Skins.  For example, you can have a `ColorPalette` that has all of your colors: `public static const ColorPalette.BRIGHT_RED:uint = 0xff0000;`, etc.  You can then use these in Flex 4 Skins via binding, such as `<mx:Button color="{ColorPalette.RED}"/>`.  The only problem with static classes is they they're not dynamic (you couldn't define an arbitrary number of colors for them).  Same with XML: you'd have to hard-code (eventually) a certain XML structure in order to use them in Skins.  You could even have the XML define ColorPalette values (so `ColorPalette.ACCENT_COLOR` could be set to anything from XML (gold, bright blue, or any accent).  Fun stuff.

**Custom Skins**:  Flex 4 allows you to easily skin all the Flex 4 and Flex 3 (datagrid, accordion, etc.).  So if you don't like how Panels only have 1 drop shadow and no gradients, you can add a background with 4 gradients and 2 dropshadows (for 2 angles of light), and maybe some rollover effect.  And then you could apply your `ColorPalette.BRIGHT_RED` to the shadow (or a glow :)).  And you could have XML configure the ColorPalette settings.  Here's a [cool custom Flex 4 Skin](http://www.hulstkamp.com/2009/07/09/custom-popup-rating-component-in-spark-flex-4-gumbo/464)

**CSS**: Then in CSS, you could write a very simple Palette parser that applied your ColorPalette values (for example) to CSS.  Check out the [Degrafa CSS Skin](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=46) for some code examples.

### Performance

The only problem with Palettes and CSS is performance.  By definition, *static class* and *binding* decrease performance.  Binding causes lots of event dispatching in the background, so things like `<mx:Button color="{ColorPalette.RED}"/>` decrease performance (not noticeable of course, since there are much worse applications, such as using built in Adobe Tweens), but it does to some degree.

Same with CSS.  In Flex, every CSS Selector (`Panel { properties:values... }` is converted into an Object.  So if you have 100 selectors, you get not only 100 extra object, but 100 extra classes in your application, at least!  And that definitely adds to your swf size.  And all of their properties are dynamic, and by definition, dynamic classes are slower than non-dynamic classes.  Plus, setting a style (with `setStyle(property, value)` in Flex is very slow because you have to loop through all the children.  If you're setting styles via an admin system (or something like Flex Style Explorer like you suggested), then you don't really care.  But because they use `setStyle()`, you can see a decent performance hit when changing styles.

So if performance was a super big issue, the best option would be to *hard code every style value*, and not change styles at runtime (who needs to do that anyway (unless your in the admin section)?).  How do you hard code styles while still remaining *agile*?  Use *Palletes* (`ColorPalette.BRIGHT_RED`) and the like, and convert the binding expressions (`<mx:Button color="{ColorPalette.RED}"/>`) to static declarations via some preprocessor (I use ruby to compile my swfs, so I just match patterns and replace).  So it'd convert `<mx:Button color="{ColorPalette.RED}"/>` to `<mx:Button color="0xff0000"/>`, and you get a performance boost.

In the end though, it's best to create custom skins and define the styles there, either through:

- static declarations `<mx:Button color="0xff0000"/>`
- palette declarations `<mx:Button color="{ColorPalette.RED}"/>`
- xml declarations `<mx:Button color="{myxml.@button_color}"/>`

Then you can define some really cool and advanced skins and have them wired up to a palette or xml file and have the user edit that.  Trying to build a very cool *and* modular skin/styling system with Flash or Flex using their built in stuff is not easy (nor desirable).  So it's best to

- create a set of skins (and package them up as a theme)
- wire skins to xml
- let user modify xml

Avoid CSS, it's too processor intensive, unless you need advanced selectors like you'd use in HTML because it does make life easy.  But for modularity and customizability (and performance), create Skins and wire them to XML.

I myself create a [basic theme](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/14/using-the-halo-theme-in-flex-4/) that I can use in all of my client projects, something that defines my style.  That consists of 3 packages (myskins, mx, spark).  In there, I copy/paste all the default Flex 3/4 skins and start customizing.  You can download a [Scale 9 Skin Project](http://scalenine.com/gallery/) for free to have most components ready to skin and test.  Then I just merge my design (photoshop or whatever) into Flex however you choose.  For all the colors I reuse, I add them to a palette and eventually to XML.  Then if I need a slightly different skin and I use that multiple times, I use CSS to define a new style for a skin (maybe a list with no background color or border).  My CSS is very lean.  Then I can just copy/paste my theme/palettes/css to new projects, modify it as needed, allow the user to edit the colors and positions via xml (or an admin interface) and I'm ready to go.

You can't do that much with just CSS.

Hope that helps.
Lance

Answer (score 0):

I've always exclusively used CSS. You stated it best that it is approachable by anyone. We can delegate the design to people that have no idea how to code in actionscript and they have no problem working with the css and the style explorer (updated for flex 3 at http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html, haven't compared too much to find out whats different vs the flex 2 version).

Answer (score 0):

If performance and flexibility are the two most important considerations for your skins, you should consider Programmatic Skins.

See: [Programmatic skinning - QuickStart](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/skinning_components/#programmatic)

To quote Adobe:

"One advantage of programmatic skinning is that it provides you with a great deal of control over styles. For example, you cannot control the radius of a Button control's corners with style sheets or graphical skins, but you can by using programmatic skins. You can also develop programmatic skins directly in your Flex authoring environment or any text editor, without using a graphics tool such as Adobe® Flash®. Programmatic skins also tend to use less memory because they contain no external image files."

Fore more info, you can also read "Creating programmatic skins" in the Adobe LiveDocs Help Docs.